# jQuery scrolling acts "funny" trying to work with offset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been breaking my head about this one but cant figure it out.
I want to scroll to an element based on the `title` attribute, in my case the element its an `h3` tag. The html looks something like this:

```
<div id="site_somesite.com" class="wrapperSite">
   <h2 class="siteName">somesite.com</h2>
   <div class="placementWrapper">
          <h3 class="placementName" title="above_01"> above_comments_01</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="placementWrapper">
          <h3 class="placementName" title="above_02"> above_comments_02</h3>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="site_anothersite.com" class="wrapperSite">
   <h2 class="siteName">anothersite.com</h2>
   <div class="placementWrapper">
          <h3 class="placementName" title=below_01"> above_comments_01</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="placementWrapper">
          <h3 class="placementName" title="below_02"> above_comments_02</h3>
   </div>
</div>
```

and my jQuery function is:

```
function scrollToPlacement(placementName){
  var target = $('h3[title~="'+ placementName + '"]').offset().top - 100;
  $("#wrapper").scroll();
  $("#wrapper").animate({ scrollTop: target});
  }
```

now, i couldnt figure out the pattern but it doesnt work...sometimes it scrolls up and sometimes down. any idea what is wrong with the way im implementing this one?

Comment: I think you should be using the 'contains' selector, not 'contains word', as the `title` attribute has no spaces (at least in your demo). Also `:first` would help when multiple elements are found. Try this: `$('h3[title*="'+ placementName + '"]:first')` Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rkj2sxok/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, can you modify your comment into an answer?

Comment: i tried using it but not helping...even when im clicking the same link twiceit scroll to top once and than back the next time

Comment: @yarivbar as you can see from the jsFiddle example, it should be working fine. Can you create an example of your issue there?